# Are there runtime checks to detect if an ARM CPU lacks SIMD features?

Tags: x86, arm, simd, neon, armv7

I'm writing a performance critical application in `C` that exploits the use of SIMD available on most processors out there. I have made my code to be compilable on multiple platforms, whether it be **ARM** or **x86**, but what are the commonly used processors/chips out there, that lack SIMD and on which my application would be inefficient?

I can't find a list of processors online that lacks SIMD, but a handful of commonly used ones, would be sufficient to convince me, that I should make a SIMD-less version of my project...

So, are there ways to detect if SIMD is available at runtime?

If I am on **x86** and using GNU GCC, then I can use  `__builtin_cpu_supports("...")` to check if a  particular feature like `avx` ,  `sse` is available.

But I cant get an equivalent *builtin* to check for ARM's neon on my **CLANG** compiler.

I don't know if such a *builtin* is available.

Comment: You'll have to define "common" and "SIMD" because you can implement some sort of SIMD even using general purpose instructions. In x86 space there is Intel Quark that lacks any dedicated SIMD instruction set extensions. In ARM, I think, ARMv7 and earlier CPUs are not required to have SIMD extensions. Such CPUs may still be relevant in embedded area.

Comment: @AndreySemashev Thankyou, Are there runtime checks to see if its available?

Comment: On x86 you would use `cpuid` instruction or one of the many wrappers, including the gcc builtins. For ARM I don't know if there is a user mode instruction, so you may have to query the OS (e.g. parse `/proc/cpuinfo`).

Comment: @AndreySemashev Thankyou! But, `/proc/cpuinfo` works only on Linux like OS  ?

Comment: Yes, `/proc/cpuinfo` is a UNIX-like interface. Also, see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26701262/how-to-check-the-existence-of-neon-on-arm

Comment: Also, this article: https://community.arm.com/developer/tools-software/oss-platforms/b/android-blog/posts/runtime-detection-of-cpu-features-on-an-armv8-a-cpu

Comment: The arm cpuid registers indicate SIMD feature support or not.